# Elementary Proof $a_n \geq 0$ and $\{a_n\} \rightarrow a$, then $a \geq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Would my proof of the following result be considered an **elementary proof**?

> If $a_n \geq 0$ for each n and $\lim{a_n} = a$, then $a \geq 0$

*Proof:*

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given.

Since $\{a_n\} \rightarrow a$

Then $\exists N_1$ for every $n>N_1$  $|a_n - a| < \epsilon/2$

Since $a_n \geq 0$

Then $\exists N_2$ for every $n>N_2$ $|a_n - 0| < \epsilon/2$

Then $|a - 0| = |a- a_n + a_n -0| \leq |a_n - a| + |a_n-0| < \epsilon$

Comment: This proof does not show that $a \ge 0$...

Comment: not sure if doing an n epsilon proof is considered elementary method, also  i guess i am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said

> Since $a_n \geq 0$
>
> Then $\exists N_2$ for every $n>N_2$ $|a_n - 0| < \epsilon/2$.

But this is not true: the second line actually means that $a_n\to 0$.

Try proving the necessity of the claim:

> If $a$ were to be a negative number, then the $a_n$ would be negative for $n$ greater than some $N$ (which goes against the assumption that $a_n\ge0$).

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be showing that the limit is 0, which is not necessarily true.

It's probably easier to think about the infimum of the sequence and how that relates to the limit, but it depends on what you are studying and what tools you have available. Also see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207784/infimum-of-a-sequence).